# How to merge two immutable object in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am working with React and Formik

Here is my validation file from where I exported two validation schema

validation.js

```
export const facValidation = Yup.object().shape({
  facebookcaption: Yup.string().required("Required"),
});
export const insValidation = Yup.object().shape({
  instagramcaption: Yup.string().required("Required"),
});
```

Now in my component I am using it like this

```
import { facValidation, insValidation } from "./validation";

<Formik
  initialValues={initialState}
  validationSchema={insValidation ? facValidation : { ...facValidation, ...insValidation }}
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
>
  {({ errors, touched }) => <Form></Form>}
</Formik>
```

Basically I have to merge both the objects conditionally. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat` to merge two schemas

```
validationSchema={insValidation ? facValidation : facValidation.concat(insValidation)}
```